# Custom component at bottom of the page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Good Day! I am creating an app where I want to create a custom footer. I have created a  separate component for the footer and imported in the main component and added a separate view for the custom footer. I am using scrollview, inside scrollview I have created a view and placed the custom footer component inside that view. The component is coming in the bottom position, but the problem is whenever I am reloading the page the bottom component comes at the top. I am getting the data from API. Before data comes the custom footer comes at the top once the data received again the component goes to the bottom. How to fix the custom component at the bottom itself if data is not there. Could anyone can help me out to fix this issue. Thanks in advance. My custom footer view style is

```
<SafeAreaView>
<ScrollView>
 <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              marginBottom: 36,
            }}
          >
            <BottomMenu {...this.props} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding min-height to the View, so that it has a height even without a content

```
<SafeAreaView>
     <ScrollView>
        <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              marginBottom: 36,
              minHeight: 400px // fix a min-height, so footer always remains at bottom
            }}
          >
            <BottomMenu {...this.props} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```